# Invalid podfile in react native fix

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

So I deleted the react native project folder from xcode and now I cant run my app on ios simulators.

Upon running npx react-native run-ios

I get the error

```
    error Cannot read property 'podfile' of null.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'podfile' of null
```

Then I tried reinstalling pod. So cd ios && pod install gave me the following error

```
    [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass.

 #  from /Users/myname/Desktop/myappname/ios/Podfile:7
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  target 'myappname' do
 >    config = use_native_modules!
 #  
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What did you delete?

Answer (score 0):

Since you deleted the Project Folder, there is not scheme.
You can learn and create a new Scheme for IOS with Xcode and build the Project or Another thing
you can discard your git changes by

```
git reset --hard
```

And your Project file will be restored build and run the project.